# Get temperature data from SensorTag as an advertisement

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am doing some works with Texas Instruments SensorTag CC2541. I am trying to show the temperature data in the advertising packets.

First, I implemented the temperature service UUID in the advertising data packet. This is done in the SensorTag.c firmware (using IAR Workbench for 8051).

```
static uint8 advertData[] =
{
  // Flags; this sets the device to use limited discoverable
  // mode (advertises for 30 seconds at a time) instead of general
  // discoverable mode (advertises indefinitely)
  0x02,   // length of this data
  GAP_ADTYPE_FLAGS,
  DEFAULT_DISCOVERABLE_MODE | GAP_ADTYPE_FLAGS_BREDR_NOT_SUPPORTED,

  0x03,
  GAP_ADTYPE_16BIT_MORE,
  LO_UINT16(IRTEMPERATURE_SERV_UUID),
  HI_UINT16(IRTEMPERATURE_SERV_UUID)

};
```

And here is the Scan Response Array:

```
// GAP - SCAN RSP data (max size = 31 bytes)
static uint8 scanRspData[] =
{
  // complete name
  0x0A,   // length of this data
  GAP_ADTYPE_LOCAL_NAME_COMPLETE,
  0x53,   // 'S'
  0x65,   // 'e'
  0x6E,   // 'n'
  0x73,   // 's'
  0x6F,   // 'o'
  0x66,   // 'f'
  0x74,   // 't'
  0x69,   // 'i'
  0x61,   // 'a'

  // connection interval range
  0x05,   // length of this data
  GAP_ADTYPE_SLAVE_CONN_INTERVAL_RANGE,
  LO_UINT16( DEFAULT_DESIRED_MIN_CONN_INTERVAL ),
  HI_UINT16( DEFAULT_DESIRED_MIN_CONN_INTERVAL ),
  LO_UINT16( DEFAULT_DESIRED_MAX_CONN_INTERVAL ),
  HI_UINT16( DEFAULT_DESIRED_MAX_CONN_INTERVAL ),

  0x03,
  GAP_ADTYPE_16BIT_MORE,
  LO_UINT16(IRTEMPERATURE_SERV_UUID),
  HI_UINT16(IRTEMPERATURE_SERV_UUID)

};
```

Then, I use a sample Bluetooth Low Energy GAT application and modify it to show the data when it is scanning. The original app was used for another beacon device and it showed the beacon name + RSSI + thermometer service when scanning. 
Here is the original code:

```
class TemperatureBeacon {

    /* Full Bluetooth UUID that defines the Health Thermometer Service */
    public static final ParcelUuid THERM_SERVICE = ParcelUuid.fromString("00001809-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");


    /* Short-form UUID that defines the Health Thermometer service */
    private static final int UUID_SERVICE_THERMOMETER = 0x1809;


    private String mName;
    private float mCurrentTemp;
    //Device metadata
    private int mSignal;
    private String mAddress;

    /* Builder for Lollipop+ */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public TemperatureBeacon(ScanRecord record, String deviceAddress, int rssi) {
        mSignal = rssi;
        mAddress = deviceAddress;

        mName = record.getDeviceName();

        byte[] data = record.getServiceData(THERM_SERVICE);
        if (data != null) {
            mCurrentTemp = parseTemp(data);
        } else {
            mCurrentTemp = 0f;
        }
    }

    /* Builder for pre-Lollipop */
    public TemperatureBeacon(List<AdRecord> records, String deviceAddress, int rssi) {
        mSignal = rssi;
        mAddress = deviceAddress;

        for(AdRecord packet : records) {
            //Find the device name record
            if (packet.getType() == AdRecord.TYPE_NAME) {
                mName = AdRecord.getName(packet);
            }
            //Find the service data record that contains our service's UUID
            if (packet.getType() == AdRecord.TYPE_SERVICEDATA
                    && AdRecord.getServiceDataUuid(packet) == UUID_SERVICE_THERMOMETER) {
                byte[] data = AdRecord.getServiceData(packet);
                mCurrentTemp = parseTemp(data);
            }
        }
    }

    private float parseTemp(byte[] serviceData) {
        /*
         * Temperature data is two bytes, and precision is 0.5degC.
         * LSB contains temperature whole number
         * MSB contains a bit flag noting if fractional part exists
         */
        float temp = (serviceData[0] & 0xFF);
        if ((serviceData[1] & 0x80) != 0) {
            temp += 0.5f;
        }

        return temp;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public int getSignal() {
        return mSignal;
    }

    public float getCurrentTemp() {
        return mCurrentTemp;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return mAddress;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s (%ddBm): %.1fC", mName, mSignal, mCurrentTemp);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the program uses the THERM_SERVICE UUID (00001809-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb) and its short form (0x1809). I tried to modify it with the SensorTag IR Temperature UUID service (F000AA00-0451-4000-B000-000000000000). And the result is that, it cannot show neither the name of the scanned device nor the temperature data.

Can you give some suggestions for this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The missing part in your question is the scan response structure in your modified SensorTag code. The `advertData` only notifies the central (iOS) of it's presence and available services (temperature). The scan response may carry more information, such as the value of the temperature. Could you post the scan response array?

Comment: I added the Scan Response array in my answer. Could you check it?

Comment: In order to send the temperature value in scan response, you can implement the following steps: 1. make room in scan response by removing `GAP_ADTYPE_16BIT_MORE ` information 2. add a new key `GAP_ADTYPE_SERVICE_DATA` and make sure adjust the data length accordingly to the size of temperature value 3. create a periodic task with a timer that would read the temperature value and store it in scan response and reconfigure the `GAPROLE_SCAN_RSP_DATA`.